# How can I use the data from the interface in a fragment?

Tags: android

I have fragment that implement interface.The data i get from the MainActivity.
The data is succsessfuly transfer to the the Fragment.
My problem is that i dont know how can i use that data.

**For Example - Fragment**

```
    public class MyAccountFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,
                                       ChangeProfileImgDialog.OnPhotoReceivedListener{

    private Uri mSelectedImageUri;
    private Bitmap mSelectedImageBitmap;

  //this the implemented methods
     @Override
public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath,Context context) {
    if( !imagePath.toString().equals("")){
        mSelectedImageUri = imagePath;
        mSelectedImageBitmap = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: got the image uri: " + mSelectedImageUri);

    }
}


@Override
public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,Context context) {
    if(bitmap != null){
        mSelectedImageUri = null;
        mSelectedImageBitmap = bitmap;
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitmap: got the image bitmap: " + mSelectedImageBitmap);
    }
}


     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);
    etAboutMe = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etAboutMe);
    tvAboutMe = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvAboutMe);
    tvProLikes = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileLikes);
    tvProFollowers = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileFollowers);
    tvProViews = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileViews);
    tvProFollowing = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileFollowing);
    tvConfirmEdits = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvConfirm);
    tvUserName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserCommentName);
    tvUserAge = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserAge);
    tvUserLocation = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
    cvUserProfileImage = (CircularImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.singleCvUserProfile);
    progressBarAcc = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progresBarAcc);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    return v;
}

    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser != null){
        progressBarAcc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        setDetailsUser();

        tvAboutMe.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvConfirmEdits.setOnClickListener(this);
        cvUserProfileImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.tvAboutMe:
            etAboutMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvAboutMe.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            etAboutMe.setText(tvAboutMe.getText().toString());
            break;
---------------- here i try to get the data from the interface ------------
        case R.id.tvConfirm:
            Log.d(TAG,"inside tvConfirm: " + mSelectedImageUri);
            progressBarAcc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            etAboutMe.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tvAboutMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvAboutMe.setText(etAboutMe.getText().toString());

            if(mSelectedImageUri != null){
                uploadNewPhoto(mSelectedImageUri);
            }else if(mSelectedImageBitmap  != null){
                uploadNewPhoto(mSelectedImageBitmap);
            }
            saveAboutMe(etAboutMe.getText().toString());
            break;
```

I'm trying to get the data from the method "getImagePath", if i log it, i do get the data. But when i want to use that data in the "onClick" when "tvConfirm" is clicked, i find that mSelectedImageUri is null. I cant understand why its null if in the method "getImagePath" the mSelectedImageUri is not null!

My main goal is the data that i receive from the interface, save it on Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Is getImageBitmap called in between? It sets mSelectedImageUri to null.

It's a bit difficult to get the function on your code in a short time, but here's a few tricks to diagnose the problem if you are using Android Studio:

1. Place the cursor at mSelectedImageUri.
2. Select Run -> Toggle Field Watchpoint. This will stop execution every time the field is changed.
3. Debug your applicaiton by selecting Run -> Debug 'app'
4. Everytime the code breaks, inspect your code. You can inspect fields by hovering the mouse over them
5. Continue execution by pressing F9. Execute one line at a time press F8.

Comment: i'll already debug, but still i couldnt find why the "mSelectedImageUri"  or "mSelectedImageBit" are null insde the "onCreatedView"

Comment: Do you know if i can create some callback from the interface method?

Answer (score 0):

Noticed in your codes:

```
@Override
public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,Context context) {
    if(bitmap != null){
        mSelectedImageUri = null; //here set mSelectedImageUri as null
        mSelectedImageBitmap = bitmap;
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitmap: got the image bitmap: " + mSelectedImageBitmap);
    }
}
```

without knowing interface definition, so only you could debug whether this method executed :)

Comment: i setted the mSelectedImageUri null here because it should be null. The main goal is that i have 2 parameters. one of them is must be null and the other one not

Comment: Do you know if i can create some callback from the interface method?

Comment: You can pass a Runable. That's very equivalent to a callback